# Processing AntiForgeryToken send with Ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

Hello I'm following [this tutorial:](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-%28csrf%29-attacks)

And I'm trying to send Ajax request which include AntiforgeryToken.
Here my ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    @functions{
        public string TokenHeaderValue()
        {
            string cookieToken, formToken;
            AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
            return cookieToken + ":" + formToken;                
        }
    }
    $('.z').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/DeviceUsage/Return",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'html',
            headers: {
                'RequestVerificationToken': '@TokenHeaderValue()'
            },
            data: JSON.stringify({ dev: { DeviceInstanceId: $('#DeviceInstanceId').val(), UserId: "1", StorageId: $('#StorageId').val() } }),
            error: function (data) {
                alert("wystąpił nieokreślony błąd " + data);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('.modal-body').html(data);
            }
        })
    })
});
```

here my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Return(DeviceUsage dev)
    {
        if(dev.StorageId==3)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Nie można oddać na własne biurko");
            ViewBag.StorageId = new SelectList(unitOfWork.storageRepository.Get(), "Id", "Name", dev.StorageId);
            return PartialView(dev);
        }
        dev.UserId = 1;
        unitOfWork.deviceUsageRepository.Update(dev);
        unitOfWork.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("MyDevices");
    }
```

But in this tutorial they show function like:

```
void ValidateRequestHeader(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
string cookieToken = "";
string formToken = "";

IEnumerable<string> tokenHeaders;
if (request.Headers.TryGetValues("RequestVerificationToken", out tokenHeaders))
{
    string[] tokens = tokenHeaders.First().Split(':');
    if (tokens.Length == 2)
    {
        cookieToken = tokens[0].Trim();
        formToken = tokens[1].Trim();
    }
}
AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
}
```

But I have no idea where to put this code in my controller and how to call this function. Can anyone explain me how to use above code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What they are showing in *Anti-CSRF and AJAX* section of the tutorial is a non-standard token validation method. In this example you would **not** use `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`, but rather run the validation manually. Firstly you inject additional header in ajax call:

```
        headers: {
            'RequestVerificationToken': '@TokenHeaderValue()'
        },
```

and then read and validate token from the header in your action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Return(DeviceUsage dev)
{
    ValidateRequestHeader(Request);
    //process action
}
void ValidateRequestHeader(HttpRequestBase request)
{
    string cookieToken = "";
    string formToken = "";

    if (request.Headers["RequestVerificationToken"] != null)
    {
        string[] tokens = request.Headers["RequestVerificationToken"].Split(':');
        if (tokens.Length == 2)
        {
            cookieToken = tokens[0].Trim();
            formToken = tokens[1].Trim();
        }
    }
    AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
}
```

Notice that `ValidateRequestHeader()` reads the header set earlier by jQuery call. Also, I've amended the method slightly to accept `HttpRequestBase`.

Tip: To avoid adding `ValidateRequestHeader()` to every controller that responds to ajax calls, add it to your base controller if you have any, and derive all controllers from the base. Or even better [create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410056%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) your own `[ValidateAntiForgeryAjaxToken]` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

For those had this issue 
the accepted answer is good but as he mentioned it 
you should create **action filter** for cleaner code
this is how I do it

> create Extention class and method

```
 public static class ExtentionUtilty
{
    public static string TokenHeaderValue()
    {
        string cookieToken, formToken;
        AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
        return cookieToken + ":" + formToken;
    }
}
```

> Use it in your cshtml and ajax call

```
$.ajax("api/values", {
    type: "post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: {  }, // JSON data goes here
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        'RequestVerificationToken': '@ExtentionUtilty.TokenHeaderValue()'
    } 
});
```

> Create an ActionFilter

```
public class ValidateHeaderAntiForgeryAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string cookieToken = "";
        string formToken = "";
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["RequestVerificationToken"] != null)
        {
            string[] tokens = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["RequestVerificationToken"].Split(':');
            if (tokens.Length == 2)
            {
                cookieToken = tokens[0].Trim();
                formToken = tokens[1].Trim();
            }
        }
        try
        {
            AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
        catch
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpNotFoundResult();
        }
    }
}
```

> and simply use it like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateHeaderAntiForgery]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult ActiveBoomSar(int id, modelDto model){}
```

Comment: You're awesome Man! I tried with the first response, but I didn't know how to create the Action FIlter! Thanks a lot!!!!!!